# Omni light disables ambient light in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, lighting

I have an ambient light attached to the scene and some objects that have attached an Omni light appear to the scene. In the moment when objects gets into the scene, the ambient light disables. Any clues why is happening that?

Comment: what do you mean by "the ambient light disables"? By default all lights apply to all objects. So it might just be that the omni light mow affects object that were previously only affected by the ambient light, and thus their appearance changes.

Comment: Kinda hard to exaplain. Ambient light is white and Omni ligh is red. When object that contains omni light appears, white light just disappers and that is all.

Comment: Could you post your code? That way we can see what's happening...

Answer (score 0):

As posted in Apple documentation:

autoenablesDefaultLighting: 
If this property’s value is false (the default), the only light sources SceneKit uses for rendering a scene are those contained in the scene graph. If you change the value to true, SceneKit automatically adds and places an omnidirectional light source when rendering scenes that contain no lights or only contain ambient lights.

tldr; the automatic lighting will be turned off if a lighting node is added that is not an ambient light-adding an omni light node to the scene will disable the auto lighting.